# Django + Angular, finding bottlenecks: which tool is this?

Tags: angularjs, django, performance

I was looking for different solution to measure and find bottleneck in my django + angularjs app.

I came accross this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199833/uwsgi-django-rest-framework-few-slow-request-after-idle-time#comment57141440_34199833). The guy has really great graphs to analyze the response time and the breakdown of event for it's app. Do oyu have an idea which tool he may be using ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what he's using, but have you tried Django Debug Toolbar? It shows the end to end times beautifully, including request, SQL, response, and DOM rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) report. It's a wonderful tool, although a bit pricey if you're just starting up.